# Scroll event not working in jQuery 1.9.1 or over

Tags: jquery, scroll, counter

I'm using a scroll event to load a new block of content when the user scrolls to specified part of the page. This works fine in jQuery 1.8.3 but using more up to date libraries it breaks. Does anyone know which part of the code is deprecated in later libraries and how I might go about updating the code?

```
$(window).scroll(function () {  
    $banner = $('#counterDisplay').position();
    $triggerPos = $('div.img:nth-of-type('+$imgNumber+')').position();
    if ($banner.top >= $triggerPos.top) {
        $counter = $counter + 1;
        $('#page').text($counter);
        $('#counter').text($counter);

        for (i = $imgNumber + 1; i < $imgNumber + 10; i++) {
            $imgDiv = "<div class='img'>" + i + "</div>";
            $('#main').append($imgDiv);
        }
        $imgNumber = $imgNumber + 9;
        $('#imgs').text($imgNumber);
        $pageHeight = $pageHeight + 1000;
        $('#container').css('height',$pageHeight+'px');
    };
});
```

Working model can be viewed here: http://jsfiddle.net/gstubbenhagen/fDAPY/11/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem appears to be the following line:-

```
$banner = $('#counterDisplay').position();
```

The `top` property is always returning `0` in newer versions of jQuery.

You can fix it by using [`offset()`](http://api.jquery.com/offset/) instead:

```
$banner = $('#counterDisplay').offset();
```

I *think* the following explains the behaviour, though I'm not sure why it behaves differently in newer versions (I couldn't find anything documenting it):

> The .position() method allows us to retrieve the current position of
> an element relative to the offset parent. Contrast this with
> .offset(), which retrieves the current position relative to the
> document. When positioning a new element near another one and within
> the same containing DOM element, .position() is the more useful.

#### [Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fDAPY/26/)

Comment: That's the winner. Well done for working that out, I'd seen offset used before but couldn't see anything in the documentation which indicated, to my mind, that it was best to use that over position.